# Get data using post request in REST API Codeigniter

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I am working with REST API for the first time in codeigniter.
I have following function in api

```
 public function cource_topics_post() {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        //$value=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->response(array('status' => 1, 'username' =>  $username ));       
    }
```

but

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
```

isn't working. need help

My controller is as follows

```
    <?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
require(APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Admin extends REST_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('file');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function cource_topics_post() {
        $username = $this->post('username');
        $password = $this->post('password');
        //$value=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $user = "faizan";
        $pass = "faizan";
        if($username == $user && $password == $pass){
            $this->response(array('status' => 1, 'logged in as' =>  $username ));
        }
        else{
            $this->response(array('status' => 0, 'Could not login' => 'incorrect username password'));
        }
    }

}
```

I am using rest_controller.

Comment: Is the data posted in json format?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have extended **CI_Controller** class in your class

Comment: You must extend REST_Controller

Answer (score 0):

check Rest config for **POST**, is activated ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameter in the function `cource_topics_post`
and second correct this

`$this->post('username');`

to

`$this->input->post('username');`